# Transfer Private Key to other devices - Flutter Encryption

Tags: flutter, dart, private-key, encryption-asymmetric, end-to-end-encryption

I am building an app which uses asymmetric encryption (each user has a private/public keypair)

Users use those keys to interact with encrypted data coming from the database.

## Problem

- User changes device.
- The private key (stored locally in old device) is not available now.

## What I know

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70728042/flutter-key-storage-for-end-to-end-encryption-across-multiple-devices) so I know that one way to do it is using a `brain key` and deriving it from a user's password.

**Problem** => I am also using `Google & Apple Login`, which don't require a password, so I can't derive the `brain key`.

## What I Need

1. The easiest way to transfer or derive the private key from the other phone's local storage (QR Code? Custom API? How does WhatsApp do it?).
2. Or a way to derive the `brain key` with other types of logins (if possible). To find the equivalent of a password when using Google or Apple login APIs, something that is secret but constant for every login on every device.

Note: The app is already live and has ~500 users with different types of logins. Encryption will be introduced in the new version.

---

**Solutions I have thought of**

Transferring through QR Codes...The old device generates a QR Code that contains the private key. The new device scans that code and gets the key.

Nothing is transferred through the internet...so is this safe?

---

Another solution is to require an 'app paassword' no matter the login type. In that way you can derive a password with social logins too.

Will this be too much strain for the user? Do other apps use this method?

Comment: A QR is an interesting choice but you'll struggle to fit all the bits you need to transfer into a QR code, especially with RSA keys.

Comment: Thanks @PresidentJamesK.Polk, plus if the user doesn't have the other device available, you're toast. The main question then is how to derive a key from social logins and how to handle people forgetting their passwords.